# date_sub ok with mysql, ko with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query which works with mySQL doesn't work with Postgresql:

```
select ... from ... where (id = ... and ( h > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)))
```

The error is:

```
Query failed: ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « 30 »
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`DATE_SUB` is a MySQL function that does not exist in PostgreSQL.

You can (for example) either use;

```
NOW() - '30 MINUTES'::INTERVAL
```

...or...

```
NOW() - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

...or...

```
NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTES'
```

as a replacement.

[An SQLfiddle with all 3 to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/894).

Comment: No need for DATE_SUB in MySQL, NOW() - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE also works for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

An interval literal needs single quotes:

```
INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

And you can use regular "arithmetics":

```
and (h > current_timestamp - interval '30' minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like :

```
select ... 
from ... 
where id = ... 
  and  h > now() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
```