# How do I get the date from seven days ago?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'd like to make a chart that gives me data from last week.

I tried to use this code but it errors out.

```
where (time_stamp::date > dateadd(day, -7, now()::date))
```

I also tried

```
(ud.time_stamp::date between now() and dateadd(day, -7, now()::date))
```

It gives me this error

> Error running query: Specified types or functions (one per INFO
>   message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [date\_sub ok with mysql, ko with postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319804/date-sub-ok-with-mysql-ko-with-postgresql)

Comment: I removed the PostgreSQL tag because it is obviously misleading.

Answer (score 12):

In Redshift, I would write this as:

```
where time_stamp >= current_date - interval '6 day'
```

I suspect that `time_stamp` might be used for partitioning and you want to be careful about comparisons involving functions on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
WHERE time_stamp > DATEADD(day, -7, current_date)
```

If you also wanted to limit the upper bound of data to today at midnight (i.e. data from last week, ending in midnight of today), you could use:

```
WHERE time_stamp >= DATEADD(day, -7, current_date) AND time_stamp < current_date
```

Comment: Redshift _does_ support casting data types using the double colon operator https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Redshift was a fork of Postgres 8, so if you remember `::` being there, then my original statement was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below option-

```
where (time_stamp::date > NOW() - interval '7 day')
```

Comment: I'm not sure that Redshift supports `interval` syntax.

Comment: Its for Postgres as tagged.

Comment: Postgres != Redshift.  Redshift is a fork from a fairly old version of Postgres.  This is why the syntax for the two databases does not always agree.

Comment: Hmmm, but I thought its a Postgres issue as OP tagged Postgres.

Comment: Intervals _are_ supported by Amazon Redshift: [Interval Literals - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_interval_literals.html)

Answer (score -1):

You haven't mentioned what the data type of the `time_stamp` column is, but assuming it's something that can be cast to `date` then I think the issue could be due to your use of the `NOW()` function which is deprecated on Redshift. Try replacing this with either `GETDATE()` or `SYSDATE` as per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html).